# Convert a decimal value to hexadecimal in a pySpark dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark, decimal

I am trying to do a simple operation, convert a decimal value to a hexadecimal value in a dataframe in pySpark.

I keep getting this error. A beginner in pySpark!

```
TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: 300561573968470656578455687175275050015353 of type <class 'int'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.
```

My Code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, expr, udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

# Create a SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

# Create a sample DataFrame with decimal values
data = [(300561573968470656578455687175275050015353,)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["decimalValue"])

# Show the original DataFrame
df.show()

# Define a UDF for decimal-to-hexadecimal conversion
def decimal_to_hex(decimal_value):
    hex_value = hex(decimal_value)[2:].upper()
    return hex_value

# Register the UDF
decimal_to_hex_udf = udf(decimal_to_hex, StringType())

# Perform decimal-to-hexadecimal conversion using the UDF
df = df.withColumn("hexValue", decimal_to_hex_udf(col("decimalValue")))

# Show the converted DataFrame
df.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

def decimal_to_hexadecimal(decimal):
    hex_digits = "0123456789ABCDEF"
    hexadecimal = ""

    if decimal == 0:
        return "0"
    
    decimal = int(decimal)

    while decimal > 0:
        remainder = decimal % 16
        hexadecimal = hex_digits[remainder] + hexadecimal
        decimal //= 16

    return hexadecimal

# Register the UDF with IntegerType return type
decimal_to_hex_udf = udf(decimal_to_hexadecimal, StringType())
```

I used this UDF on the data frame, had no issues with the datatype.

`df.withColumn("columnName", decimal_to_hex_udf(col("columnName")))`

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import format_number, format_string
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
data = [(300561573968470656578455687175275050015353,)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["decimalValue"])
# Convert decimal to hexadecimal
df = df.withColumn("hexadecimalValue", format_string("%X", "decimalValue"))
```

Can you try this and check
[image]

Comment: This generated all `null` values